# Run acceptance tests multiple times to find success ratio (java)

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, gradle, junit

I have a package of JUnit classes that represent my acceptance tests. I am coding a simulation with some randomness and I discovered that for a few of these tests there is a small probability of failure.

What I'd like to do is to run all the tests in the package multiple times and store their success ratio in a csv file.
Each line would be the name of the test and the success ratio.

Is there an automated way to do this with JUnit or Gradle (which I am using for this project)?

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with just using core Java?  You can keep a tally of how many times a test passes, and then write this out to CSV yourself right before your test suite finishes.

Comment: Yes that is my current approach. However these tests take a bit  and I  miss gradle's multithreaded testing. I could obviously instantiate an executor myself but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't control or remove the randomness?

Comment: For unit tests I obviously can and do. For acceptance tests I musn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to code this yourself in your buildfile.
Something like creating N tasks with names `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, ... with identical configuration. This would probably look something like:

```
(1..10).each {
    task "test$it"(type: Test) {
        // configuration of the test task
    }
}
```

And then you have to try either using [TestReport](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.html) which can create a test report over multiple test tasks results, though I didn't use it yet, so I don't know how it will look like and if it gives the result you intend,
or alternatively you use [afterTest](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:afterTest%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) when configuring your test tasks and collect your statistics there. You can then additionally declare a task that depends on all your test tasks and output your statstics in its execution phase.